# Databound RibbonTab is displaying RibbonGroup content in "Header"

Tags: wpf, binding, mvvm, ribbon

I have an observableCollection of "RibbonGroupViewModel".

The view of each viewModel is defined like that :

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:RibbonGroupViewModel}">
        <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="test">
//....
</ribbon:RibbonGroup >
    </DataTemplate>
```

And to display Ribbon :

```
 <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="Home">
                <ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Client">
                <ribbon:RibbonCheckBox Label="bouton2"></ribbon:RibbonCheckBox>
                </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RibbonGroupCollection}"></ItemsControl>
            </ribbon:RibbonTab>
```

THe new RibbonGroup is added to my ribbon but the display is not correct....

**See ScreenShot**

[image: screenshoot]
http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/8584/screenshot300d.jpg

the second group is in "other" level... very strange

Just for information, if I don't use ItemTemplate (first RibbonGroup), all is ok

Comment: Can you please ask your question without linking to another question?  It may result in your question being closed.  Take a screenshot of your issue, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7736425/edit) and add the image.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be, that ItemsControl does not just inserts a bunch of RibbonGroups, but wraps them in a StackPanel.

If thats it, you could add your "Client" group to the RibbonGroupCollection and bind to the ItemsSource property of the RibbonTab.